# Происхождение слова "заповедный"

Tags: этимология

Как я понимаю, от родственно слову "заповедь". Но при чем тогда заповедник?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отношение самое прямое:

заповедь-заповедать, заповедный - заповедник

http://my-dictionary.ru/word/9086/zapovedat

Заповедь - это религиозно-нравственное предписание, часто запрет: не убий, не укради...От него есть ещё глагол заповедать - завещать исполнить заповедь, повеление,запрет.

Заповедный - неприкосновенный по заповеди, запретный.Например, "Запове́дные ле́та" (также заповедные годы, от «заповедь» — повеление, запрет) — годы, в течение которых в некоторых районах Русского государства запрещался крестьянский выход в осенний Юрьев день

Заповедник -заповедные земли, участок территории, на котором сохраняется в естественном состоянии весь его природный комплекс,там действует запрет на убийство(охоту) , уничтожение природы.

Answer (score 2):

Потому,  что  в  заповедниках  ЗАПРЕЩЕНО  охотиться.  Одно  из  значений  слова  "заповедь" - запрет.  В  17-м  веке  годы,  в  которые  закрепощённые  крестьяне  не  имели  права  покидать  помещика,  называли  заповедными.

Answer (score 2):

У Ожегова:

ЗАПОВЕДЬ,   1.  Религиозно-нравственное   предписание.  Десять библейских заповедей.  2.  перен.  Правило,  положение, служащее руководящим указанием для кого-чего-н. (высок.).

ЗАПОВЕДНЫЙ,     1.  Неприкосновенный,  запретный.   3.  лес. Заповедное  озеро.  2.  Хранимый  в  тайне, заветный. Заповедные  мысли.

ЗАПОВЕДНИК,  -а, м.  Заповедное  место, где  оберегаются  и сохраняются редкие и  ценные растения, животные,  уникальные участки природы, культурные ценности.

Получается, что заповедник - это неприкосновенная, запретная территория, что устанавливается особым указом.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

В то же время "заповедными местами" можно назвать не только территорию заповедника, но и просто дикую, нетронутую,первозданную природу, как, например, у Высоцкого: "В заповедных и дремучих, страшных Муромских лесах Всяка нечисть бродит тучей и в проезжих сеет страх".