# Корень в слове "заповедник"

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор

В словарях у слова "заповедник" указывается корень -заповед-. Почему? Ведь глагол "ведать" еще жив и словообразовательная модель вроде как активна.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Близкая по содержанию тема обсуждалась на форуме https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30363/Происхождение-слова-заповедный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Разбор по составу**: заповед/н/ик, корень заповед- и два суффикса

Формальная словообразовательная цепочка выглядит так: ведать — поведать — заповедать — заповедный — заповедник.

Однако в современном языке мы рассматриваем только ее часть: заповед/а/ть — заповед/н/ый — заповед/н/ик. Другой вариант: заповед/а/ть —  заповед/ник. Это следует из словарных статей для этих слов.

В языке до сих пор существуют глаголы ***ведать*** (знать) и ***поведать*** (рассказать).

У глагола ***заповедать*** приставка ЗА обозначает строгую обязательность предписания. Вторым же значением глагола становится **терминологическое значение:** сделать заповедным, заповедником.

Но при изменении значения глагол становится **непроизводным** и образует **новую словообразовательную цепочку.**

Из словаря:

ЗАПОВЕДАТЬ,  св. что. Высок. 1. Предписать исполнить что-л. как заповедь (2 зн.); завещать. З. сыновьям жить в родной деревне. 2. **Спец. Сделать заповедным (1 зн.), заповедником.** З. озеро, рощу.

ЗАПОВЕДНЫЙ,  **1. Оберегаемый государством; неприкосновенный. З-ые луга. З-ые пруды.**

ЗАПОВЕДНИК,  м. Заповедный участок земли или водного пространства, где оберегается и сохраняется в естественном состоянии весь его природный комплекс, а также культурные ценности.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли толкование приставки за-? И вы ничего не сказали про морфемный состав слова.

Comment: Приставка ЗА обозначает полную завершенность действия, отсюда следует неукоснительность соблюдения того, что сказано.

Answer (score 1):

Это *условность* современного толкования и расчленения слов (подобное можно найти и для "подсолнечника" - корень "подсолн"). Вот старинный источник, в котором корень слов "заповедный" и др. (в старом написании) **-вед-**, а начальная часть **запо-** трактуется как "*два предлога*" (в совр. наименовании - "*приставки*"):

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=M3FgAAAAMAAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA355&img=1&zoom=3&sig=ACfU3U0fNbpKBz-Qd3K2AK8xG42YKLccAQ&w=1025

(А. Шишков, Собраніе сочиненій и переводовъ, 1825, Том 5, с. 355)

Comment: Подсолнечник все-таки обладает другой историей: там предлог слился с существительным; в заповеднике такого не было.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное потому, что смысл у них разный. Ведать - жив, однако ранее был еще и глагол ведети. А вообще, если бы в русском языке всё бы было так очевидно, то он тогда бы, наверное, и не назывался бы русским), а старославянской речью, например. Каждый язык, в том числе, подразумевает и создание его личных (собственных) правил, а также и исключений из них. Например, отсутствие в русском языке приставки "па" при наличии таких слов как падчерица, пасынок и т.п.

Ваш пример сродни - заподозрить.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопрос первый.** С чего вы взяли, что в современном русском языке глагол *ведать* 'знать' как-либо соотносится со элементом *-вед-* в слове *заповедник*? Даже истолковать одно через другое невозможно! Как минимум поэтому выделять корень *-вед-* не стоит.

**Вопрос второй.** Допустим, корень таки *-вед-*, тогда как объяснить значение части *запо-*? Ну, на материале современного русского языка — никак.

Корень *заповед-* выделяется потому, что слово [«унаследовано»](http://www.drevoslov.ru/vedatitree/6073-zapovednik) из старославянского (есть, однако, предположение, что это собственно русское слово, но слишком уж книжное у него значение; хотя, может, это действительно исконное слово — трудно сказать), а значит, будучи носителем русского языка, происхождение слова *заповедник* трудно проанализировать (см. выше).

Другое дело — исторический анализ. При нем, безусловно, выделяется корень *-вед-*, потому что существительное *заповедник* появилось в результате следующего развития:
ведать – поведать — заповедать — заповедь — заповедный — заповедник.

Comment: Ну, я могу согласиться, что слово "заповедник" сейчас действительно имеет только терминологический смысл (или переносный от него), и здесь, действительно, уместно выделять корень -заповед-. Но вот выделять его в слове "заповедь", как мне кажется, ошибочно - а именно такой вариант дан в Викисловаре. В этом слове корень -вед- смысла не утратил, и цепочка еще сохраняет актуальность.

Comment: Слияние приставки с корнем - не такое уж и редкое явление. Просто при разборе слова нужна внимательность, а ее не всем хватает. Можно согласиться, что, к примеру, в словах "совет", "ответ", "завет", "привет" корень именно такой, поскольку глагол "ветить" исчез веке этак в двенадцатом (хотя глагол "вещать" остался). Но с глаголом "ведать" это произойдет, я думаю, не раньше, чем лет через сто-двести.

Comment: @Зина я не могу отвечать за Викисловарь -- там много неточностей. А почему, по-вашему, корень -вед- можно выделять в _заповеди_? Как объяснить смысловую связь?